# jquery: how to remove the previous element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do i remove a previous element to the triggering one with jquery?

i have tried:

```
$(this).prev().remove();
$(this).next().remove();
```

but nothing works!

Comment: Can you give us example HTML to work from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Be sure jQuery is properly referenced, and all of your syntax is correct:

```
$("li").click(function(){
  $(this).prev().remove();
});
```

Works with:

```
<ul>
  <li><p>Don't delete me!</p></li>
  <li><p>Click me to delete him!</p></li>
  <li><p>Click me twice, to take 'em both out!</p></li>
  <br/> <!-- line break added after OP's comments -->
  <li><p>Click me to remove the line-break!</p></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6):

Often when seemingly correct jQuery syntax doesn't work (especially with traversing) it is often because you are operating on the wrong element. Take a look at this HTML:

```
<div>
  Please remove me
</div>
<div>
  <span>Click to remove</span>
</div>
```

Now, if we wired this up with a `click` event on the `span` it is important to first call `parent()` to get the containing `div`, and then get the previous element:

```
$("span").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().prev().remove();
});
```

A simple call to `$(this).prev().remove()` would fail because the `span` is the only child of the `div`.

Answer (score 1):

The exact code you posted [works for me](http://pastehtml.com/view/5soduhs.html).

Note that `this` is always set to an element in e.g. a jQuery `click` handler, but not in other JavaScript functions (unless you arrange for it to happen that way).

Comment: ok yeah it worked for me now. but i wanted to remove a <br /> tag after the clicked link. i tried $(this).next('br').remove() but it didnt work. u got any idea?

Comment: OP, see my example - this method removes breaks too.

Answer (score 0):

We'll be better able to answer your question if you provide a little more context. Note that this won't necessarily point to the current element unless you are within the context of a handler. What are you trying to achieve here?